# Why is every positive integer the sum of 3 triangular numbers?

Tags: number-theory

Why is every positive integer the sum of at most 3 triangular numbers ?

Comment: You mean at most 3 triangular numbers, I suppose?

Comment: I consider 0 a triangular number so ...

Comment: No, the title is correct.  "At most 3 triangular numbers" would mean that there is no integer which is the sum of 4 triangular numbers.

Comment: See [Fermat's polygonal number theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatsPolygonalNumberTheorem.html).

Comment: @Lucian Fermat's polygonal number theorem is much more general and harder then the eureka theorem. Its related yes. But the proof of the polygonal requires the eureka and four squares I think.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Every positive integer $\equiv 3\mod{8}$ can be written as a sum of three squares; see [here](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Ankeny57.pdf) for a proof (in fact, more integers than just those can be so written).

The result about triangular numbers follows from that result: let $n>0$; then $8n+3$ is a sum of three squares. From congruence conditions modulo $4$, it follows that each square is odd, so that
$$ 8n+3 = (2x+1)^2 + (2y+1)^2 + (2z+1)^2 = 4x^2 + 4x + 4y^2 + 4y + 4z^2 + 4z + 3,$$
so that
$$ 8n = 4x(x+1) + 4y(y+1) + 4z(z+1).$$
The result follows upon dividing through by $8$.

Comment: there is a trick due to Aubry, about 1912, that proves that the sum of three squares integrally represents any integer that it rationally represents. This is in Serre's little book.

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, I've seen that. Looking at that book again, he goes on to give essentially the proof above for triangular numbers as well. But that observation does not simplify the three squares proof, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: In that paper I see on page 3 : (14) If p/q, then (5), (-m/p) = l.
Im confused about that step. Plz explain. Thank you.

Comment: @mick Equation (5), if $p\mid q$, says that $-m$ is a square mod $p$, which is $\left(\frac{-m}{p}\right) = 1$.

Comment: Oh yes ! @rogerl thank you ! +1