# Gauss' "Eureka" theorem

Tags: reference-request, sums-of-squares

Gauss proved that every integer is expressible as the sum of three triangular numbers. I was wondering if the proof is anywhere to be found?

Comment: there is a proof [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1028404/why-is-every-positive-integer-the-sum-of-3-triangular-numbers), but it relies on the 3 square theorem

Comment: Gauss proved it without using the three square theorem.

Comment: are you sure about that? My latin is very bad, but on [art 293](http://edoc.hu-berlin.de/ebind/hdok2/h284_gauss_1801/pdf/h284_gauss_1801.pdf) (page 515 of the pdf) Gauss proves the results you're interested in and it seems to use the fact that every integer of the form $8M+3$ can be written as the sum of 3 squares. Anyway, whether the proof uses the 3 squares theorem or not it was published by Gauss in the book I linked, I'm not sure whether you need someone who can read Latin or whether there is an English version